# Create custom listview with two images in parallel in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I just started working on android Kotlin. I want to build an android application in which endless-scroll have a custom list-view. Now I want this list view to display two images box parallel with un-even height. Please ref below image for clear understating.

[custom listview](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Of5qL62tBGM48f5uk0AyduZmi3R2dUTY)!

**Note**: Due to new user with less reputation, I am not able to attache image so sharing image link

Comment: use StaggeredGridlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for RecyclerView with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Here is a tutorial for that: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html